# How to integrate cucumber reporting utility with karate framework?

Tags: cucumber, karate

We have replicated similar code to the one mentioned in the documentation(using ReportBuilder) to generate cucumber html reports.
we are able to get response for the API call but in reports we are getting error as

"we are  getting com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: http call failed after 977 milliseconds for URL: "

Method used:

```
 private static void generateReport() {
    String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
    Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
    List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
    for( File file: jsonFiles)
    {
    jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "demo");
    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();        
    }
    }
```

This function is called at the end of feature file.
Please help on resolving this issue.

Comment: in my opinion, the question is un-clear and does not have enough information to replicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the same test using the JUnit runner (refer the doc) and fix the problem.

`http call failed after 977 milliseconds for URL` means this is a problem with your test, nothing to do with reporting.

Comment: please let me know is there way to get cucumber report without parallel execution because for each case execution, report is running separate one thread.

Comment: yes, karate is designed to work like this. if you run using the api (see doc) you will not get the report. all the best.